Creating a Typescript Project with Support for Web Workers?
I'm trying to create a Typescript project that supports web workers.
First I create a baseline that will compile typescript code like this.
mkdir ts
cd ts
npm init -y
npm i -D typescript
npm i -D @types/mocha

Add tsconfig.json.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2021", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "types": ["mocha"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": []
}

Add some typescript (src/hello.component.ts).
/**
 *  @category WebComponent
 *
 * Hello World Web Component
 * that renders a greeting.
 */
export class HelloWorldComponent extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['name'];
    }
  
    /**
     * The name to greet
     * @defaultValue World
     */
    name: string | null = 'World';
    something!: string;
    /**
     * Initializes the name property to `World`.
     */
    constructor() {
      super();
      //    this.name = 'World';
    }
  
    /**
     * Sets the component inner
     * html to the greeting.
     */
    connectedCallback() {
      this.textContent = `Hello ${this.name}!`;
    }
  
    //========================================
    // attribute change callback
    //========================================
    attributeChangedCallback(
      property: keyof HelloWorldComponent,
      oldValue: string | null,
      newValue: string | null
    ) {
      if (oldValue === newValue) return;
      switch (property) {
        case 'name':
          this.name = newValue;
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error(`Unhandled attribute: ${property}`);
      }
    }
  }
  customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorldComponent);

And run tsc.
This compiles fine.
And the only step left to add web worker support is to add it to the lib compiler option like this.
"lib": ["es2021", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "WebWorker"],

And rerun tsc.  However now it generates creates all these errors.  Any ideas?
tsc
../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ImportExportKind, TableKind, ExportValue, Exports, ImportValue, Imports, ModuleImports, ValueType, name, AlgorithmIdentifier, AllowSharedBufferSource, BigInteger, BinaryData, BlobPart, BodyInit, BufferSource, CSSKeywordish, CSSNumberish, CSSPerspectiveValue, CSSUnparsedSegment, CanvasImageSource, DOMHighResTimeStamp, EpochTimeStamp, EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, FileSystemWriteChunkType, Float32List, FormDataEntryValue, GLbitfield, GLboolean, GLclampf, GLenum, GLfloat, GLint, GLint64, GLintptr, GLsizei, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLuint64, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, HeadersInit, IDBValidKey, ImageBitmapSource, Int32List, MessageEventSource, NamedCurve, OffscreenRenderingContext, OnErrorEventHandler, PerformanceEntryList, ReadableStreamController, ReadableStreamReadResult, ReadableStreamReader, ReportList, RequestInfo, TexImageSource, TimerHandler, Transferable, Uint32List, XMLHttpRequestBodyInit, AlphaOption, AvcBitstreamFormat, BinaryType, CSSMathOperator, CSSNumericBaseType, CanvasDirection, CanvasFillRule, CanvasFontKerning, CanvasFontStretch, CanvasFontVariantCaps, CanvasLineCap, CanvasLineJoin, CanvasTextAlign, CanvasTextBaseline, CanvasTextRendering, ClientTypes, CodecState, ColorGamut, ColorSpaceConversion, CompressionFormat, DocumentVisibilityState, EncodedVideoChunkType, EndingType, FileSystemHandleKind, FontDisplay, FontFaceLoadStatus, FontFaceSetLoadStatus, GlobalCompositeOperation, HardwareAcceleration, HdrMetadataType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionDurability, IDBTransactionMode, ImageOrientation, ImageSmoothingQuality, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, LatencyMode, LockMode, MediaDecodingType, MediaEncodingType, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, OffscreenRenderingContextId, PermissionName, PermissionState, PredefinedColorSpace, PremultiplyAlpha, PushEncryptionKeyName, RTCEncodedVideoFrameType, ReadableStreamReaderMode, ReadableStreamType, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestPriority, RequestRedirect, ResizeQuality, ResponseType, SecurityPolicyViolationEventDisposition, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, TransferFunction, VideoColorPrimaries, VideoEncoderBitrateMode, VideoMatrixCoefficients, VideoPixelFormat, VideoTransferCharacteristics, WebGLPowerPreference, WebTransportCongestionControl, WebTransportErrorSource, WorkerType, WriteCommandType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType

23 interface AddEventListenerOptions extends EventListenerOptions {
   ~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:23:1
    23 interface AddEventListenerOptions extends EventListenerOptions {
       ~~~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:3632:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

3632     [index: number]: CSSNumericValue;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5234:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

5234     [index: number]: CSSTransformComponent;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5290:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

5290     [index: number]: CSSUnparsedSegment;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:6471:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

6471     [index: number]: string;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:8412:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

8412     [index: number]: File;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ImportExportKind, TableKind, ExportValue, Exports, ImportValue, Imports, ModuleImports, ValueType, name, AlgorithmIdentifier, AllowSharedBufferSource, BigInteger, BinaryData, BlobPart, BodyInit, BufferSource, CSSKeywordish, CSSNumberish, CSSPerspectiveValue, CSSUnparsedSegment, CanvasImageSource, DOMHighResTimeStamp, EpochTimeStamp, EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, FileSystemWriteChunkType, Float32List, FormDataEntryValue, GLbitfield, GLboolean, GLclampf, GLenum, GLfloat, GLint, GLint64, GLintptr, GLsizei, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLuint64, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, HeadersInit, IDBValidKey, ImageBitmapSource, Int32List, MessageEventSource, NamedCurve, OffscreenRenderingContext, OnErrorEventHandler, PerformanceEntryList, ReadableStreamController, ReadableStreamReadResult, ReadableStreamReader, ReportList, RequestInfo, TexImageSource, TimerHandler, Transferable, Uint32List, XMLHttpRequestBodyInit, AlphaOption, AvcBitstreamFormat, BinaryType, CSSMathOperator, CSSNumericBaseType, CanvasDirection, CanvasFillRule, CanvasFontKerning, CanvasFontStretch, CanvasFontVariantCaps, CanvasLineCap, CanvasLineJoin, CanvasTextAlign, CanvasTextBaseline, CanvasTextRendering, ClientTypes, CodecState, ColorGamut, ColorSpaceConversion, CompressionFormat, DocumentVisibilityState, EncodedVideoChunkType, EndingType, FileSystemHandleKind, FontDisplay, FontFaceLoadStatus, FontFaceSetLoadStatus, GlobalCompositeOperation, HardwareAcceleration, HdrMetadataType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionDurability, IDBTransactionMode, ImageOrientation, ImageSmoothingQuality, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, LatencyMode, LockMode, MediaDecodingType, MediaEncodingType, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, OffscreenRenderingContextId, PermissionName, PermissionState, PredefinedColorSpace, PremultiplyAlpha, PushEncryptionKeyName, RTCEncodedVideoFrameType, ReadableStreamReaderMode, ReadableStreamType, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestPriority, RequestRedirect, ResizeQuality, ResponseType, SecurityPolicyViolationEventDisposition, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, TransferFunction, VideoColorPrimaries, VideoEncoderBitrateMode, VideoMatrixCoefficients, VideoPixelFormat, VideoTransferCharacteristics, WebGLPowerPreference, WebTransportCongestionControl, WebTransportErrorSource, WorkerType, WriteCommandType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType

23 interface AddEventListenerOptions extends EventListenerOptions {
   ~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:23:1
    23 interface AddEventListenerOptions extends EventListenerOptions {
       ~~~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:1234:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

1234     [index: number]: CSSNumericValue;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:1266:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'CSSNumericValue' must be of type '{ new (): CSSNumericValue; prototype: CSSNumericValue; parse(cssText: string): CSSNumericValue; }', but here has type '{ new (): CSSNumericValue; prototype: CSSNumericValue; }'.

1266 declare var CSSNumericValue: {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:3664:13
    3664 declare var CSSNumericValue: {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'CSSNumericValue' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:1355:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'CSSStyleValue' must be of type '{ new (): CSSStyleValue; prototype: CSSStyleValue; parse(property: string, cssText: string): CSSStyleValue; parseAll(property: string, cssText: string): CSSStyleValue[]; }', but here has type '{ new (): CSSStyleValue; prototype: CSSStyleValue; }'.

1355 declare var CSSStyleValue: {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5189:13
    5189 declare var CSSStyleValue: {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'CSSStyleValue' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:1383:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

1383     [index: number]: CSSTransformComponent;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:1424:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

1424     [index: number]: CSSUnparsedSegment;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:2247:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

2247     [index: number]: string;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:2763:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'number'.

2763     [index: number]: File;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:3075:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'FormData' must be of type '{ new (form?: HTMLFormElement | undefined, submitter?: HTMLElement | null | undefined): FormData; prototype: FormData; }', but here has type '{ new (): FormData; prototype: FormData; }'.

3075 declare var FormData: {
                 ~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:8758:13
    8758 declare var FormData: {
                     ~~~~~~~~
    'FormData' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:4185:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Notification' must be of type '{ new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions | undefined): Notification; prototype: Notification; readonly permission: NotificationPermission; requestPermission(deprecatedCallback?: NotificationPermissionCallback | undefined): Promise<...>; }', but here has type '{ new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions | undefined): Notification; prototype: Notification; readonly permission: NotificationPermission; }'.

4185 declare var Notification: {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16699:13
    16699 declare var Notification: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'Notification' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:5693:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'URL' must be of type '{ new (url: string | URL, base?: string | URL | undefined): URL; prototype: URL; canParse(url: string | URL, base?: string | undefined): boolean; createObjectURL(obj: Blob | MediaSource): string; revokeObjectURL(url: string): void; }', but here has type '{ new (url: string | URL, base?: string | URL | undefined): URL; prototype: URL; canParse(url: string | URL, base?: string | undefined): boolean; createObjectURL(obj: Blob): string; revokeObjectURL(url: string): void; }'.

5693 declare var URL: {
                 ~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:22904:13
    22904 declare var URL: {
                      ~~~
    'URL' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9187:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onmessage' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any) | null'.

9187 declare var onmessage: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: MessageEvent) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28270:13
    28270 declare var onmessage: ((this: Window, ev: MessageEvent) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~~
    'onmessage' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9189:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onmessageerror' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any) | null'.

9189 declare var onmessageerror: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: MessageEvent) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28272:13
    28272 declare var onmessageerror: ((this: Window, ev: MessageEvent) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'onmessageerror' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9216:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'location' must be of type 'Location', but here has type 'WorkerLocation'.

9216 declare var location: WorkerLocation;
                 ~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:27594:13
    27594 declare var location: Location;
                      ~~~~~~~~
    'location' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9222:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'navigator' must be of type 'Navigator', but here has type 'WorkerNavigator'.

9222 declare var navigator: WorkerNavigator;
                 ~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:27611:13
    27611 declare var navigator: Navigator;
                      ~~~~~~~~~
    'navigator' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9224:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onerror' must be of type 'OnErrorEventHandler', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: ErrorEvent) => any) | null'.

9224 declare var onerror: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: ErrorEvent) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:27967:13
    27967 declare var onerror: OnErrorEventHandler;
                      ~~~~~~~
    'onerror' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9226:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onlanguagechange' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null'.

9226 declare var onlanguagechange: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28268:13
    28268 declare var onlanguagechange: ((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'onlanguagechange' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9228:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onoffline' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null'.

9228 declare var onoffline: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28274:13
    28274 declare var onoffline: ((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~~
    'onoffline' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9230:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ononline' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null'.

9230 declare var ononline: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28276:13
    28276 declare var ononline: ((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~
    'ononline' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9231:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onrejectionhandled' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null'.

9231 declare var onrejectionhandled: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28284:13
    28284 declare var onrejectionhandled: ((this: Window, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'onrejectionhandled' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9232:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onunhandledrejection' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null'.

9232 declare var onunhandledrejection: ((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:28288:13
    28288 declare var onunhandledrejection: ((this: Window, ev: PromiseRejectionEvent) => any) | null;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'onunhandledrejection' was also declared here.

../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:9238:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'self' must be of type 'Window & typeof globalThis', but here has type 'WorkerGlobalScope & typeof globalThis'.

9238 declare var self: WorkerGlobalScope & typeof globalThis;
                 ~~~~

  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:27695:13
    27695 declare var self: Window & typeof globalThis;
                      ~~~~
    'self' was also declared here.


Found 28 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     6  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:23
    22  ../../.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:23


Typescript bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/59850

OK - As indicated by MartinJohns on this Github Issue we can't use DOM and WebWorker at the same time.
Shortening lib to this fixes it.
"lib": ["es2021","WebWorker"],

